# Restrict Draggable To be Dropped Only if it is Completely Inside the Droppable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Take a look at this demo and let me know how I can force jQuery UI to Drop the draggable inside Droppable ONLY if the draggable is Completely inside the droppable?

```
$(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
        $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this )
                    .find( "p" )
                        .html( "Dropped!" );
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the tolerance option to fit. 
Change your script to

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({tolerance: "fit", drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this ).find( "p" ).html( "Dropped!" );
    }
```